# Storing a matrix from a text file into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble storing a matrix from a text file into a 2D array. Every time I run the following code, it executes with no errors but nothing is printed out in the console. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input1.txt"));
        String [][] array = new String [9][9];

        try{

            for(int i = 0; i > array.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = sc.next();
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                }

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("error");

        }
```

Also this is the content of the text file I am reading in:

```
5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2
6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8
1 9 8 3 4 2 5 6 7
8 5 9 7 6 1 4 2 3
4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1
7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6
9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4
3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9
```

Comment: you should change `for(int i = 0; i > array.length; i++)` to `for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`

Comment: @Eritrean why not post that as an answer? That's the problem he has.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your first loop, also it's better to use `nextInt()` when the content of `"input1.txt"` is `int`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input1.txt"));
        int [][] array = new int [9][9];

        try{

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
                }

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("error");

        }
```

Comment: your nextInt will not compile Mohsen_Fatemi, you forgot yo change String array to int array

Comment: @GeorgeWeekson look at the code first :/ the type of array is `int`

Comment: Not sure this is correct anyway, doesn't OPs file contain string representations of ints, not actual ints.

Comment: Forgot if `Scanner.nextInt()` reads literal ints or string ints

Comment: Scanner has type. it will read what type you invoke. nextInt, nextDouble, nextFloat, nextBigDecimal so on and so on, if it can not read @InputMismatchException will be thrown, for example if you have numbers and try to store them in boolean array. that will end up with exception.

Comment: @George Weekson Yes.. but I was forgetting if `Scanner.nextInt()` would read the bytes "1234" as the int '1234' or as the int '825373492'. It seems that `Scanner.nextX()` is always parsing a String into X.

Comment: @GeorgeWeekson Yes.. I know, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you have error in first for loop

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input1.txt"));
    String [][] array = new String [9][9];

    try{

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // your error was here. you wrote int i = 0 i > array.length; i++
            for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = sc.next();
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("error");

    }
```

Comment: @JohnFore yes, happens.